# How can I run an infinite loop on my website? (for a reminder/deadline announcer)

Tags: php, javascript

I'm building a website and i want to implement a reminder feature that alerts people if they have any projects or activities that are due or simply alert them of any timer they may have set. I have a clue about how i could do it with javascript's timer functions but i want it to run all the time and add reminders to a queue if the users are not online when the event occurs. Is there any way of doing this or do i have to use bash or python on the server?

Further explanation on how it's supposed to work:
 - infinite loop checks for the time every X seconds, if there's a a reminder up between now and X seconds ago, print it to the user it belongs to - if the user is not online, put it in a file or something which is checked, when the user logs in, for any missed reminders.

another way i thought of is to use a local script (pyton or something) to check the database for reminders that are due, every X seconds, and write them in a file on the web server. then,  server-side scripting will read it every X seconds and print the reminders to each logged account (and delete it at that point). This way no reminders are skipped even if the person it belongs to is logged out.

Any idea on how to do this more elegantly?

Comment: it can be done with cron jobs but it is better to do it without because it can take up too many resources especially with many users,many reminder conditions and short check intervals. cron is usually used for maintenance (for example periodically [once a day] deleting all offline links from db). and what will you do when the user is logged in and a reminder event occurs? cron can not handle this... you'll need ajax to call a php file to check if there are new reminders. so why not call that page also when a user logs in?

Comment: @kasper Taeymans: "cron can not handle this" [citation-needed] - in fact, I've worked on several systems that did exactly this (running a PHP script, from cron, once per minute), and it worked fine, without melting the server. Of course, it required some thinking beforehand - such as: one process checks reminders for each user in turn (not one process per user), the process and the queries it calls are streamlined, etc. Note that the cron script itself can be in PHP; AJAX is completely unrelated.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans: cron can handle this imo, running a job more than once is exactly what it is for. the limitations regarding resources affect the script that is being run, not cron itself afaik.

Comment: Of course cron can handle this. But there still needs to be process that checks the results of this cronjob if you want to show a user a new reminder on a page he has ALREADY loaded. So apart from making the problem smaller, a cron job does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this functionality can be done with ajax and php. I wouldn't check the db when the user isn't online. I guess it is better to check reminders on login (unless you want to for example email them when they occur->then you need cron like mentioned in the other answers). you'll need to make a php script that checks which reminders have to be set and return them in an array/json. on login call this page. when user is logged in you can request your reminder php periodically/timer with ajax.

Comment: I ended up using this in the end. Just started a script on login that starts a loop which checks for all the reminders up until <now>. I talked to the manager and he said e-mails and optimisation can wait, we got a deadline to make (altho we probably wont)

Comment: I'm happy you did the job! I reckon it is the right way to do it... No optimization needed. you can use cron later on for email functionality. you could fire the email script (for example) every hour and email all occurred events at the same time. peace

Answer (score 3):

Use [Cron Job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) instead and run your script with that to connect to your database and to do other tasks.

Comment: Why, you only have placed the problem to checking a different source? The script still needs to check the result of the cronjob somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Having an infinite loop is by default bad design. PHP won't like it at all (memory). Javascript isn't ideal for the same reason too. Apart from that you don't want a javascript sleep to block your UI when waiting between tries.

Also, I wouldn't check notices when the user is not online. This is a useless way of using resources. Simply save the last time a user was online and display past notices that he hasn't seen before on login.

The cleanest solution in my book is some javascript library capable of eventdriven actions. An example of that is [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). With events you don't need to check every N time but simply have an event triggered if some condition is met.